# Ruby On Rails on eHost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to just upload my RoR files to my server (eHost) and have my website up and running?
If not, what should I do in order to have it working on any Host with support for RoR? I know of heroku but it is quite expansive for me right now. eHost charges only $3.27 per month and they claim to have support for RoR. I even called Tech Support and asked them to update the vertion to 2.3.0(Ruby) and 4.2.4(Rails).
I am new on RoR and have no idea of how to host my application on the ordinary hosts out there. So any help will be very welcome.

Comment: Did you try using Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, I only hope this gives you an idea,

They say they support Ruby and RoR, So taking a look https://support.ehost.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-and-gems  they say it's on Apache CGI server.

So - this is my suggestion - you upload your project, and either you contact support or you might want to try the suggestion here:

http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/52-how-to-install-a-ruby-on-rails-app-part-2  I'll quote the section (in case it ever becomes unavailable). It's under the section FastCGI/CGI:

*Configure .htaccess
Apache usually looks in any web directory for an Override file(which lets you set your own Apache configuration settings for the directory) called .htaccess. For ruby on rails, we need a special .htaccess file that tells the server to set up the directory as a ruby on rails application. This file should be created in the public directory if it's not already there. Here's what the contents of the file should look like:*

```
#AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi  
#AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi  
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi  
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI  

RewriteEngine On  

RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]<br>RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.cgi [QSA,L]  
ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Rails application failed to start properly"
```

*Linking to public
The public directory inside your rails application contains all your public resources(images, css, javascript, etc.), and well as the .htaccess file needed to run your application. Until now, your public directory hasn't been visible to the outside world. Now we'll link your application to a directory inside your web root.
For example, if I was planning on running my rails application in a subdirectory of my website called www.mywebsite.com/myrailsapp, you'll need to create a symbolic link(it's kind of like a shortcut) in your web root directory(remember, this is where your regular website stuff goes, usually named public_html or www). Let's also pretend that on the server, the path to your web root is /home/myaccount/public_html and the path to your rails application is /home/myaccount/myrailsapp. Therefore, the command to create a symbolic link will be:*

```
ln -s /home/myaccount/myrailsapp/public /home/myaccount/public_html/myrailsapp
```